# ajax call for core API 3.1 model is null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Core MVC Ajax Call not hitting to Core API 3.1 (running in two different ports)

```
var objGetAttachment = {};

    objGetAttachment.DocumentRef = $('#docinfoId').attr('data-DocumentRef');
    objGetAttachment.IdentifiedFormForDocumentRef = $('#docinfoId').attr('data-IdentifiedFormForDocumentRef');
    objGetAttachment.Queueref = $('#docinfoId').attr('data-QueueRef');
    objGetAttachment.SubQueueRef = $('#docinfoId').attr('data-SubQueueRef');
    objGetAttachment.TaskTypeRef = $('#docinfoId').attr('data-TaskTypeRef');
    objGetAttachment.IsArchivedReadOnlyData = $('#docinfoId').attr('data-IsArchivedReadOnlyData');
objGetAttachment.Action = 2;

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: apiURL + '/api/Attachment/GetAttachments',
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        data: {
            objGetAttachment: objGetAttachment
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success'); 
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert('failure'); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error'); 
        }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAttachments(Attachment objGetAttachment)
    {
    
    }
```

Comment: Hello, could you please include your backend code? Additonally add your full client side code how  you are getting `ajax` post request data

Comment: i have updated. Please review

Comment: Please have a try, if you encounter any problem feel free to share.

Comment: Hello was the problem resloved? Let me know if you require any further assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way:

**Model:**

```
public class Attachment
    {
        public string DocumentRef { get; set; }
        public string IdentifiedFormForDocumentRef { get; set; }
        public string Queueref { get; set; }
        public string SubQueueRef { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAttachments")]
    [ActionName("GetAttachments")]
    public ActionResult GetAttachments(Attachment objGetAttachment)
    {
        return Ok(objGetAttachment);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function (e) {

            var DocumentRef = "Test DocumentRef";
            var IdentifiedFormForDocumentRef = "Test IdentiDocumentRef";
            var Queueref = "Test Queueref";
            var SubQueueRef = "Test SubQueueRef";
            var Action = "Test Action";

            var objGetAttachment = {
                DocumentRef: DocumentRef,
                IdentifiedFormForDocumentRef: IdentifiedFormForDocumentRef,
                Queueref: Queueref,
                SubQueueRef: SubQueueRef,
                Action: Action,
            };

            $.ajax("https://localhost:44346/api/Attachment/GetAttachments", {
                method: "GET",
                data: objGetAttachment,
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

> **Note:** Point that in `objGetAttachment` json model property should same as your `Attachment` Class other than you will get null value.

Hope it will help you. If you still have any concern let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you better use Post to submit such a big chunk of data

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiURL + '/api/Attachment/GetAttachments',
        data: {
            objGetAttachment: objGetAttachment
        },
           success: function (data) {
            alert('success'); 
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert('failure'); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error'); 
        }
    });
```

and remove attribute GET from action

```
[Route("~/api/Attachment/GetAttachments")]
public ActionResult GetAttachments(Attachment objGetAttachment)
....
```